# Is there a safe way to kill a named python process from within Shell script?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, kill

Summary : Attempting to stop a python3 script safely from within shell.

I am able to kill my python3 script (called, 'getphotos.py) but am concerned that killing the process while a photo is being saved, may lead to a corrupted sd card.

Is this something I need to worry about? If so, is there a more suitable command that I could use and one that checks first if the actual script is running before quitting/exiting ?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi
pgrep -f getphotos.py # will give you its pid
pkill -9 -f getphotos.py # kills the matching pid
date >> killit.txt
```

Comment: Does your OS use systemd?

Comment: The `kill` command sound worse than it actually is. By default, it sends a `SIGTERM`. You can use the `signal` library to handle this and exit gracefully.

Comment: The SD card *cannot* be corrupted by this scenario. A specific file on the SD card may be corrupted, but the filesystem on the SD card cannot, because the responsibility for maintaining the filesystem is with the OS not with a user program. And don't use `kill -9` unless strictly necessary; a simple `kill` (or `kill -TERM`) ought to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if there are any open handles to picture files:

```sh
(lsof -p $(pgrep -f getphotos.py) | grep -q jpg) || pkill -9 -f getphotos.py
```

This will kill the process only if `lsof` did not return any `jpg` files.

Comment: But the `lsof` result may or may not still be applicable when the `pkill` is run